# Need help on join table, limiting results to only the resource ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey all I have a block of code that utilises 3 models...

```
class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :trans
    has_many :sellers, :through => :trans
    validates :seller_id, presence: true

end

class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :trans
    has_many :buyers, :through => :trans
    validates :buyer_id, presence: true


end

class Tran < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :buyer
    validates :buyer_id, presence: true
    belongs_to :seller
    validates :seller_id, presence: true

end
```

Suppliers - has_many trans, has_many buyers through trans

Trans - belongs_to buyers, belongs_to sellers

In my seller_show view I can execute the following code and successfully give me a list of the seller's Buyers, with a sum of all their transactions. That's all good *however* the sum shows **all** the buyer's transactions, not limited to the ones with the sellers.

I've tried loads of different ways to try and limit the transactions where the seller_id = trans.supplier_id (foreign key), but can't seem to make it work.

Can anyone help? Thank you very much in advance!

(FYI, 'sum' is confusingly the title of the column hosting the transaction amount in the trans table!)

```
<ol>   
<% @seller.buyers.uniq{|t| t.buyer_id }.sort_by {|su| su.trans.sum(:sum)}.reverse.each do |su| %>   
<li><%= su.name %> <%= su.trans.sum(:sum) %></li>   
<% end %> 
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways I see that you can do this.  The simpler approach (albeit less efficient in the sorting), would be to aggregate the sums by `buyer_id` and then inject that into the list of buyers:

```
<% buyer_sums = @seller.trans.group(:buyer_id).sum(:sum) %>
<% Buyer.where(id: buyer_sums.keys).sort_by {|b| -buyer_sums[b.id]}.each do |buyer| %>
  <%= buyer.name %> <%= buyer_sums[buyer.id] %>
<% end %>
```

A second approach would be to fetch the sums together with the buyer:

```
<% Buyer.joins(:trans).merge(@seller.trans).
         select("buyers.*, SUM(`sum`) sums").order('SUM(`sum`)').each do |buyer| %>
  <%= buyer.name %> <%= buyer.sums %>
<% end %>
```

The advantage of the second approach is that you aren't sorting after retrieving the entire collection, which matters for scalability especially as related to pagination.

Note that the backtick (`) escape character used here is for MySQL, but should be replaced with the appropriate DB convention if otherwise (e.g. double quote for PostgreSQL).  Alternatively, use the `quote_column_name` method to do this smarter :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, getting errors on both. The first one gets the error; undefined method `buyer_id' for #<Buyer:0x54ff9f0> - sorry for the amateur reply, but where would I define the method to make it work?

Comment: Second error is; PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 1: SELECT buyers.*, trans_sums.sums FROM "buyers" (SELECT buyer...

Comment: Sorry, `buyer_id` should have simply been `id` when referring to the buyers table, and I missed the word JOIN on the second method - updated.

Comment: You are a beautiful individual - THANK YOU!

Comment: @thegreengiant Updated with a 'cleaner' version of the second method - good luck!

Comment: thanks...tried to find a 'PM' function on here to offer to PayPal you money for a coffee but couldn't find :-/